# How to parse the data from JSON iOS

Tags: json, swift

I am building an app in iOS using **SWIFT** and i have also been using swiftyJSON to make this project a little easier.

```
func parseJSON(){
    let path : String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("jsonFile", ofType: "json") as String!
    let url : String = "http://www.thegoodsite.org/attend/api.php?users_id=1"
    let nsurly = NSURL(string: url)
    let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfURL: nsurly!) as NSData!
    let readableJSON = JSON(data: jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)

    var Name = readableJSON

    numberOfRows = readableJSON["People"].count //Ignore this for the question



    NSLog("\(Name)")

}
```

I am loading this data from a url so if going to include a picuture of the data im getting back in the console.

[CLICK THIS LINK TO SEE IMAGE OF WHAT THE CONSOLE SAYS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZQUa.jpg)

So what code do i need to add to get the email to come out as text.

```
var Name = readableJSON ["users","email"]
```

However when I do that to the code I seems not to get any data at all.

How can I edit this code to get the email like I want?

Comment: Post your console output as plain-text--not a link to a photograph of a screen with the console output on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let users = readableJSON["users"]
let user = users[0] // get info of the first user, you should check more here
let email = user["email"]
```

Or (as @nhgrif's cmt):

```
if let users = readableJSON["users"], user = users.first, email = user["email"]
```

Comment: `if let users = readableJSON["users"], user = users.first, email = user["email"]`

Comment: @nhgrif Thank you. I use `[0]` for the OP can adjust it likes `[i]`, or something like that.

Comment: The `[0]` will crash if the array is empty.

Comment: @nhgrif how can I get that email as a string

Comment: @BrandonMayU please try before asking.

Answer (score 0):

I play the code,then i found the result of Json if Dictionary, so use the  `var Name = readableJSON["users"]!![0]["email"]`

Comment: not if Dcitionary,is Dictionary<array[Dictionary]>, sorry,